# Приложение для андроид не принимает SMS

Tags: java, android, sms

Код Android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
<!--        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
<!--        </activity>-->
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBotReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

код обработки сообщений

```
public class SMSBotReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
    if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("SMSReceiverService","Incoming SMS tut...tut..tut...");

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msgFrom = "";
        String msgBody = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if (bundle != null){

            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    msgFrom = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgPart = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    stringBuilder.append(msgPart);
//                        Log.d("Incoming Message", "SMS From " + msgFrom + ", Content: "+ msgPart);

                }
            

    // Dispatch Event
    //                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new NewMessageEvent(msgFrom, stringBuilder.toString()));
                    Log.d("Wrapped message", "Wrapped Message from "+msgFrom+" is: "+stringBuilder.toString());

//                    this.abortBroadcast();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("SMS Receiver", "Intent is not sms"+intent.getAction());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: версия андроид 11

Comment: Вам сюда https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request